# Angular2+ safe navigation operator?

Tags: typescript, angular5, angular2-services, safe-navigation-operator

I've been using angular2+ for some time, and I found the 'safe navigation operator' a very useful syntax, but now I have a question if I can write a generic service or sth to handle the 'null' thing instead of write '?.' everywhere.

Comment: Just an opinion, but I'd use that operator sparingly. Using it all over your templates shows that you're really not in control of your data.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen We just got our project upgraded from AngularJS 1.x, so the template is still have a bit 'ng1' style.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yep, I agree with what you said. But technically I just curious about this.